# String interpolation in graphQL query

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, gatsby

I am new to Gatsby and its graphQL query system to retrieve assets. I have a working component `Image` that fetches an image and displays it. I want to have the name of the image customizable but I can't figure out how to dit.

Here is the working component:

```
const Image = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        // fetching the image gatsby-astronaut.png
        placeholderImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "gatsby-astronaut.png" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => <Img fluid={data.placeholderImage.childImageSharp.fluid} />}
  />
);
```

And here is what I tried to have a customizable image:

```
const Image = ({ imgName }: { imgName: string }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        // fetching the image imgName
        placeholderImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "${imgName}.png" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => <Img fluid={data.placeholderImage.childImageSharp.fluid} />}
  />
);
```

But it raises the following error for the query:

`Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)`

How can I have a customizable image name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the easy way I ran into:

```
const Image = props => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      firstImg: file(relativePath: { eq: "firstImg.png" }) {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }

      secondImg: file(
        relativePath: { eq: "secondImg.png" }
      ) {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  switch (props.name) {
    case "firstImg":
      return <Img fluid={data.firstImg.childImageSharp.fluid} />
    case "secondImg":
      return <Img fluid={data.secondImg.childImageSharp.fluid} />
    default:
      return <Img />
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<Image name="firstImg" />
```

You can also make it typo-safe by introducing an object with all the images you might want to display, like this:

```
const Images = { firstImg: 'firstImg', secondImg: 'secondImg' }
```

and then use it like this:

```
<Image name={Images.firstImage} />
```

and

```
...
switch (props.name) {
case Images.firstImage:
...
```

Comment: Very convenient

Answer (score 3):

Check [the docs for static query](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/#how-staticquery-differs-from-page-query)

> StaticQuery can do most of the things that page query can, including fragments. The main differences are:
>
> - page queries can accept variables (via pageContext) but can only be
>     added to page components
> - StaticQuery does not accept variables (hence the name “static”), but
>     can be used in any component, including pages

So you might want to query for the image's `GatsbyImageSharpFluid` in your page query and pass it as the fluid prop directly to gatsby image.

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work but your answer is relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using ksav answer I managed to make this work by using pageQuery and receive the images i want to use in a specific page through [props](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/#provide-data-to-the-homepage--component).

Like this:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  coverImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "coverImage.png" }) {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

If you add this to your page component you will receive the props coverImage with the coverImage.png image.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is one area where Gatsby could do better imho. I appreciate @ramzesenok's answer and if you must use the Gatsby framework with graphql that's probably the best you're going to do. But you could also just fall back to [normal React](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import gatsbyAstronaut from './gatsby-astronaut.png';
```

and use it like this.

```html
<img src={gatsbyAstronaut} alt="Gatsby Astronaut" />
```

Even this seems a little heavy but the import is required so webpack can bundle the image properly.